# Изображение в качестве ссылки

Tags: html, css, python, django

Как можно реализовать изображение в качестве ссылки в `django`
пробывал так, но ссылка работает только по верхней линии, а не по всей картинки.

```css
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -7px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="{% static "rss_news/logo.png" %}"  height="50px" border="0" alt=""></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#logo {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a href="https://ya.ru"><img src="http://333v.ru/uploads/00/000a7db0d4c688263a3e8d09e1f5fa93.jpg" height="50px" border="0" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как я понял это все из-за позиционирование.

Comment: не только, <a>, строчный эл. его надо было расстянуть на весь блок  display: block;, ну позиционирование... что бы фото и ссылка были друг на друге

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за дополнительную информацию.

Comment: Блин чувак сори, новичок здесь)

Comment: все ок)))) ))))